# Output resistance and transconductance in the calculation of NMOS common source voltage gain

Tags: mosfet, small-signal, transconductance

For a NMOS, the transconductance gm is defined as id/vgs at a fixed VDS.
However when we calculate the small signal gain of a common source amplifier, we use vds = -id x RD and then vds = -gm x vgs x RD.

Why we can substitute id as gm x vgs? according to the definition of gm, it is defined as id/vgs at a fixed VDS, but here the VDS has the change in vds in the equation.

A similar issue is that the output resistance ro, defined as id/vds at a fixed VGS. but why we can still use ro for calculation when the equation contains vgs?

Do I miss anything here?

Comment: I think this is because, these are *small-signal* quantitites, i.e. they apply for a given operation point and for small deviations thereabout.

Comment: Also questions like this would be more readable, if you used MathJax notation, i.e. instead of `gm x vgs`, write `\$g_m V_{gs}\$` to obtain: \$g_m V_{gs}\$

Answer (score 1):

> Why we can substitute id as gm x vgs?*

Because, if you draw the **small signal equivalent model** of the common source:

[image]

Image [source](https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Small-signal-model-of-common-source-amplifier_fig1_311309718).

you should "see" that \$i_D = gm * v_{GS}\$.

Note how I write \$i_D\$ and not \$I_D\$.

\$i_D\$ is the **small signal current** so actually the derivative of \$I_D\$.

\$I_D\$ is the actual drain current that you would calculate with for example: \$I_D = K_p \frac W L (V_{GS}-V_t)^2\$)

> gm, it is defined as id/vgs at a fixed VDS, but here the VDS has the change in vds in the equation

Yes correct **BUT** you should separate:

**small** signal parameters (\$gm, i_D, v_{GS}\$) and

**large** signal parameters (\$I_D, V_{GS}\$)

The small signal ones are the ones where we:

- assume the transistor is biased at a certain operating point (a certain \$I_D\$ and \$V_{GS}\$)
- assume that we apply **small signal** (\$v_{GS}\$) so that the circuit operates in a linear fashion (no distortion)

Then we can use the small signal model and parameters.